# How can I check from the command line if a pull request on GitHub is blocked due to insufficient reviews?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to identify using a script if the pull request of mine is blocked and whether it is blocked due to insufficient reviews.

For example, it may be defined in the branch protection rules in GitHub that a pull request must have two reviews in order to merge, and those reviewers must not be the same person who made the last commit.

So how can I see if this is one of the reasons the merge is blocked?

I want to output to the user a list of things that are blocking the pull request at the moment - and this is just one of those things.

Comment: Generally, using the GitHub CLI, you can get pretty far with `gh pr <number> view --json reviews,reviewDecision`, but you still have to add some post processing.

Comment: @BenjaminW. that syntax you provided doesn't work. However, that pointed me in the right direction. I posted the solution below.

Comment: Whoops, should be `gh pr view <number>`, but then you can access the PR directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BenjaminW for pointing me in the right direction.
I used the gh cli tool from GitHub and jq:

```bash
$PR_ID=<your_pr_id>
gh pr list --json number --json reviewDecision | jq --arg PR_ID "$PR_ID" '.[] | select(.number == ($PR_ID|tonumber)).reviewDecision' | tr -d '"'
```

In which case the output is either APPROVED or REVIEW_REQUIRED